# Calling class method results in "the name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms program that contains a `MainForm` class, as well as another class called `Communication`. This program is supposed to show some data on transactions. The problem is that I need to put the `DisplayData` method in my `MainForm` class, and I need to call it a few times in `Communication`.

I understand that I should call the main class on top of the `Communication` class, but I still get this error:

> Error 1   The name 'DisplayData' does not exist in the current context

This is my code:

```
MainFormClass.DisplayData(MessageType.Error, ex.Message);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see more/all of the code. It _appears_ as thought you are calling that method as if it is static. Perhaps it is not? Regardless, show more/all of your code if you can for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Communication
    {
        public void CallDisplayDataMethodFromMainForm()
        {
            string message = MainFormClass.DisplayData(1, 2).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }

    public partial class MainFormClass : Form
    {
        public MainFormClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static int DisplayData(int a, int b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to call your `DisplayData()` method in such a context, you need make it `static`.